# Mark sources folder automatically in PyCharm

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there a possibility to mark specific folders automatically as sources? We have a kind of large monorepo with following structure

```
services/
  service1/
    src/
  service2/
    src/
...
```

We want to mark all `src/` folders as sources automatically. It this possible at all? Maybe with a plugin?

Comment: Hi, did you see the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Well yes and no, and there's a plugin.

- **Yes:** PyCharm is smart enough to mark the `src/` folders as [sources roots](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/content-root.html#root_types) **if they are installed** in a virtual environment (for example using [development install](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/installing-packages/#installing-from-a-local-src-tree)) and that [Python Interpreter is set](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html) in the Project Settings.
- **No:** There is no configuration in the IDE to do it automatically by folder name. You can add the sources roots by editing them into the [project configuration files](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/setting-up-your-project.html#storage). You'd have to edit the following files in the `.idea` folder and details may vary depending on your project layout:

  1. The sources root itself is defined in `your_project_name.iml` file

  ```xml
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <module type="PYTHON_MODULE" version="4">
     <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
       <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
         <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/src" isTestSource="false" />
       </content>
       <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
     </component>
  </module>
  ```

  2. Then in `workspace.xml` in the `.idea` folder adding the sources root is configured in the project manager

  ```xml
  <component name="RunManager">
     <configuration name="main" type="PythonConfigurationType" factoryName="Python" nameIsGenerated="true">
       <option name="ADD_SOURCE_ROOTS" value="true" />
  ```
- **Plugin**: If you want to use a plugin there's this one [Python Path Assistant](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/13785-python-path-assist) that allows you to: *"managing source folders via external file"* which automates the previous option of editing the IDE configuration files.